# How to use tryCatch in R?

Tags: r

```
for(i in 2:num_asset){
  assetclass <- ts(mydt[,i])
  tryCatch(
    {
      fit <- Arima(assetclass,order = c(2,0,2))
    },
    error = function(e){
      fit <- auto.arima(assetclass)
      k=i
    }
  )
  fst <-as.data.frame(forecast(fit, h=52))
}
```

I want to run code above. But It doesn't work showing message below.

> Error in forecast(fit, h = 52) : object 'fit' not found

My intention is ...
If there is an error in first function( `fit <- Arima(assetclass,order = c(2,0,2))` ) then, I'd like to run second function(`fit <- auto.arima(assetclass)`)

How should I do?

Comment: [how to write try-catch in r](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12195574/5977215)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of your error is that the following line is referring to the `fit` variable, which does not exist in the scope in which it is being referenced:

```
fst <- as.data.frame(forecast(fit, h=52))
```

One option would be to just have the try catch return the value of `fit`, whatever it be based on success or error:

```
for (i in 2:num_asset) {
    assetclass <- ts(mydt[,i])
    fit <- tryCatch({
        return(Arima(assetclass,order = c(2,0,2)))

    }, error = function(e) {
        k=i
        return(auto.arima(assetclass))
    })

    fst <- as.data.frame(forecast(fit, h=52))
}
```

Comment: thanks. It works well. Good!